# Responsive image sizing with vertically centered text in List items

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

My goal is to have 3 images side by side that have vertically and horizontally centered text inside, and have the images **Responsive**

From my understanding, when vertically centering something in a parent element, the parent element is supposed to be absolute, and the child is supposed to be relative and translated -50% after doing top: 50%.

I have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozyJBP

but something seems to be wrong. When I comment out the position: relative and then uncomment it, it never reverts back to the way it was.

I'm trying to keep the aspect ratio of the images, but now I can't even figure out why the text won't vertically center. My real code more closely resembles the bottom UL.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>On Sale</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180"/></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Special Offers</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Must Have</p><img src="http://placehold.it/300x180"/></a></li>
</ul>

<br><br><br><br><br>


        <ul id="offersList">
            <li id="onSaleBG">
                <div class="offers">On Sale</div>
            </li>
            <li id="specialOffersBG">
                <div class="offers">Special Offers</div>
            </li>
            <li id="mustHaveBG">
                <div class="offers">Must Have</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

ul li p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #2f3134;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}



#onSaleBG {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x180) no-repeat;
}

#specialOffersBG {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x180) no-repeat;
}

#mustHaveBG {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x180) no-repeat;
}

.offers {
    background: #2f3134;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#offersList li {
    height: 180px;
    width: 300px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: better use a img-responsive class

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/yh91u4z1/1/ are you want something like this ?? it's actually problem when you set div in side ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your `translate` setting: To use it both for the x *and* y axis, you have to write it like this (inside `ul li p`), otherwise the second `translate` will overwrite the first one:

```
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Also, you have to add `margin: 0` to this rule to reset the default margins. So the complete rule is:

```
ul li p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  background: #2f3134;
  color: white;
}
```

Codepen with this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXAbVy

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox on the `#offersList li` element and remove the `top` and `transform` attributes on `.offers`

```
#offersList li {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a display: table on the wrapper and table-cell on the children. It is the easiest way to vertically align without the clutter of an actual table. Plus they'll line up with each other, be responsive if the cells are set to 33.3% wide, and can be overridden easily for mobile to put the images vertically.